# Call function without assigning returning value based on syntax diagram

Tags: syntax, pascal, abstract-syntax-tree, bnf

From [Peter Grogono's "Programming in PASCAL" Addison Wesley 1980](http://primepuzzle.com/tp2/syntax-diagrams.html), a statement is defined as:

[image]
[image]

In this diagram, I don't see how I can call the function as a statement; the only way to call it is to make a new temporary variable, then assign it with the desired function as an expression.

How can I call function without assigning the returning value?

Comment: The version of Pascal described by this diagram apparently DOESN'T have any ability to call a function as a statement; you can only call a procedure (3rd branch from the top).  There is a lot of variation between Pascal implementations, I don't know how common this restriction is.

Comment: @jasonharper Beside `ISO 7185:1990` specs, do you know any other Pascal official specs till date?

Comment: Yes.  Standard Pascal is rigid about function return values. If you don't need the return value, you'll have to use a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [Pascal ISO 7185:1990](http://www.pascal-central.com/docs/iso7185.pdf) specs, I see that Pascal doesn't support `function-statement`. So the only way to call them is by using temporary variables.

```
simple-statement =
      empty-statement
    | assignment-statement
    | procedure-statement
    | goto-statement
```

Comment: IIRC,calling functions as statements was not part of the early Turbo Pascals either. Only later, the function result could be discarded.

Comment: Even now you need extended syntax enabled to use function statements.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What do you mean by "exented syntax" in Turbal Pascal?

Comment: @MiP I'm referring to what Turbo Pascal became, Delphi

Comment: Look up switch $X+